# How i sort The Crystal report when passing Group by query

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports

I have a report (which is in crystal report 9) . I send a query from VB 6 to crystal report like.

```
qur = "SELECT  copmanyid, product_name, trans_date1, bno, mrp, exp_date, Sum(quantity) As qty , Sum(bonus) As bon From  q_saledetail Where trans_date1=# " & dt1.Value & " # and (invno between " & Val(Text1.Text) & " and  " & Val(Text2.Text) & ") and tid='SV'   Group By  copmanyid, product_name, bno, mrp, exp_date, trans_date1  ORDER By copmanyid "
```

this is query is selected from q_saledetail which have invno, trans_date1 and tid and filed below:

But when its open in crystal report then result is look like this: (which is Not sorted by companyid

```
Companyid    product_name   Packing   mrp bno     exp_date       qty    bon
 201016       CARBAPIN     20TAB     165  40      30-Dec-17      100    0
 201011      CITOFAST     10TAb      260  61      30-Oct-17      30     0
 201011      COGIN SYP    10TAB      270  I003    30-Jun-18       50    0
 201011      MELONEX      2MG.       460  TD51    30-Mar-17       20    0
 201011      NEULIN TAB   10TAB      680  TD53    30-Mar-17       4     0
 201016     OLONCO 3      25TAB       93  0002    30-Oct-17       50    0
 201016     OLONCO 6      25TAB      156  0002    30-Oct-17        50    0
 201011      TOPAMID      50M.       200  762     30-May-17       30    0
```

What i Do???

Comment: I can see no order format given.. give whether it is to be sorted by asc or desc in query

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a Group in Crystal Reports based on the Companyid. This will sort it, and allow headers and footers for each Companyid if you want them.